# UIProgressView have different position at runtime

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiprogressview

I place a UIProgressView on an XIB file. At first it goes well. After when I set its height via auto layout to be 20, problem occurred. The Progress View always got its position at the most top-left of the screen. even I use

```
[self.progress setFrame:CGRectMake(93, 100, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

still don't work for me at all.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: don't set frame when using autolayout, use instead constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use size constraints as outlets. Then you can easy change values of those constraints. It's not really recommended to modify frame when using auto-layout.

declare a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint;
```

and in the implementation:

```
 self.heightConstraint = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;
 self.widthConstraint= self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
```

Alternatively you can try to set frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but it's not recommended when using auto-layout.

Comment: Solved! I tried to do it in viewDidLayoutSubViews and it worked.